# SQL: Choose from an array of items in a like clause with AND condition

Tags: sql, arrays, ms-access

I am trying to write some SQL which really needs an array of like this string and that string and so on, and to meet a datetime condition and make this syntax work as it should. All of this is psuedocode.
For example 
[DueDate] >= someDateTimeControl.Value AND [Place] like "A", "B", "C"

So that only those places which qualify on the due date are also shown, A, B, C.
I tried using AND [Place] like "A" Or [Place] like "B"... (so on) with the  DueDate but it gets those places which do not meet the due date. So how would you array it so I could get the time and the place as any in the set that meet the time?

```
Private Sub Text168_AfterUpdate()
Dim membershipCutoff As String
Dim checkForAll As String
checkForAll = Me.Combo164.Value
If checkForAll = "All" Then
membershipCutoff = "Select * from [Members]"

ElseIf checkForAll = "All Members" Then
membershipCutoff = "Select * from [Members] where ([Expire] >= #" & Me.Text168 & "# And ([MembType] Like IN ('A' , 'B', 'C' , 'D') And  [MembType] Not Like 'E'))"

Else
membershipCutoff = "Select * from [Members] where ([Expire] >= #" & Me.Text168 & "# And [MembType] = '" & Me.Combo164 & "')"
End If
Me.Members_subform.Form.RecordSource = membershipCutoff
Me.Members_subform.Form.Requery
End Sub
```

Comment: you should show the actual query used.

Comment: Okay I put the actual query on it.

Comment: I tried the IN clause, but I also need a not like statement or maybe not? Otherwise like I said before I said use the date condition, AND like A, B, C,... so on and not like E

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`like in` won't work. You should use either of them. You should replace it with `and` or `or` conditions.

```
 Select * from [Members]
 where [Expire] >= #" & Me.Text168 & "# 
 And [MembType] IN ('A' , 'B', 'C' , 'D') And  [MembType] <> 'E'
```

If you are searching for a pattern, consider using `like`. For what you are trying to do, `in` would suffice.

Comment: Trying out your example... one moment.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you for your help.